# How to simulate a dough or silly putty?

Tags: animation, physics

I want to simulate a dough like material getting stretched or squashed in different places. My first aim is to animate a rolling pin flattening the dough on a flat surface. Is there any way to simulate this physically on Blender?

Comment: Lookup Molecular Addon

Comment: That addon looks like it is something to simulate a lot of small rigid objects like sand. I am looking for a way simulate one elastic object.